# SSIS Package Not Working if trying to deploy programatically

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis

I have developed a simple SSIS package in VS2015. Instead of deploying this to a SQL Server for scheduling I am going to have a desktop application for now that kicks the job off manually.

If I go to the location on my local machine and I double click on the Package.dtsx file, it opens a Execute Package Utility. If I click on execute it runs the package perfectly fine and all steps succeeed.

When I create a desktop application and execute it from their like this (this is Microsoft code for how to manually deploy a local SSIS Package):

```
            string pkgLocation;
            Package pkg;
            Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app;
            DTSExecResult pkgResults;
            pkgLocation = @"C:\SSIS\TestSSIS\Package.dtsx";
            app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

            if (pkgResults.ToString() != "Success")
            {
                if (pkg.Errors.Count > 0)

                {
                    string errors = "";
                    int errorID = 0;

                    foreach (DtsError error in pkg.Errors)
                    {
                        errors = errors + error.Description.ToString();
                        errorID++;
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(errors + "Total Error Count:" + errorID.ToString() );
                }
```

I get some error messages:
For each step in the process I get this error:

> To run a SSIS Package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install [Step Name] of Integration Services or higher.

That specific error doesn't make any sense. I have seen notes that it is a MS Bug that the error is wrong but none of the solutions applied so far to my situation. Any ideas how we can resolve this?

Comment: Do you have SSIS installed on the machine you are running your app. This error is *DTS_E_SSISSTANDALONENOTINSTALLED* from [MS Error List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345164.aspx). Another possible situation - you reference assemblies versions of which are not available at testing station.

Comment: Another [similar discussion on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726801/running-an-ssis-package-developed-in-sql-server-data-tools-for-visual-studio-201?rq=1). Author ended with reinstalling SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Posting here incase it helps someone else. It turns out the error itself can take on many meanings. In my case

```
ASSEMBLY: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
```

It had 2 versions, a 12.0 and a 13.0. I inadvertently didn't add the correct assembly version so it appeared to the application that I didn't have SSIS installed.

*Honorable mention to @Ferdipux for pointing out that assemblies could cause this and for researching the MSErrorList.*